# React use a value from different component (in form submit)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Basically, I have a form. I want to use a query builder inside of it. I used https://github.com/ukrbublik/react-awesome-query-builder for conditions. So this is the component:

```
const queryValue = {"id": QbUtils.uuid(), "type": "group"};


export default class QueryBuilder extends Component {
    state = {
      tree: QbUtils.checkTree(QbUtils.loadTree(queryValue), config),
      config: config
    };
    
    render = () => (
      <div>
        <Query
            {...config} 
            value={this.state.tree}
            onChange={this.onChange}
            renderBuilder={this.renderBuilder}
        />
      </div>
    )

    renderBuilder = (props) => (
      <div className="query-builder-container" style={{padding: '20px', backgroundColor: "white"}}>
        <div className="query-builder qb-lite">
            <Builder {...props} />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
    
    onChange = (immutableTree, config) => {
      this.setState({tree: immutableTree, config: config});

      const jsonTree = JSON.stringify(QbUtils.mongodbFormat(immutableTree, config));
      // THIS IS THE RESULT I WANT TO USE WHEN I SUBMIT THE FORM
    }
}
```

I used this component inside my form component basically looks like this;

```
 <form >
<input> </input> 
<input> </input>
</<QueryBuilder />
<button type="submit">  </button> 
</form>
```

So this works fine in UI, however, I can't capture the query when I submit the form.  I can console log the query from QueryBuilder component, it works fine as well. What is the best way to reach that result in my form? I tried to export the const but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your state for your query in your form component.

```
  const [query, setQuery] = React.useState('')
```

pass setQuery as a prop:

```
<QueryBuilder setQuery={setQuery}/>
```

in your query component you can use prop to set a query state:

```
onChange = (immutableTree, config) => {
   this.setState({tree: immutableTree, config: config});

  const jsonTree = JSON.stringify(QbUtils.mongodbFormat(immutableTree, config));
  **this.props.setQuery(jsonTree)** 
}
```

now you can use your query inside your form.